# CSS Animating Nav elements on :hover

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a standard nested UL nav structure and some CSS to animate the sub-navs on `:hover` ...

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kwsV/

Everything is working as expected with exception of the animation on the deepest UL.  The first subnav animates height, the second one should animate width only.

Here is the code which handles the animation of the deepest UL which I am having issues with.

```
nav ul li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

nav ul li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

Now, the issue with the above code is that when hovering over the "Michael" nav label, the width and the height animates.  It needs to animate width only.  It would seem the solution is fairly obvious, change "all" to "width".

Si I change this...

```
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
```

To this...

```
    -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
       -moz-transition: width 0.6s ease;
        -ms-transition: width 0.6s ease;
         -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
        transition: width 0.6s ease;
```

Now, when hovering, the animation animates for width 0 to 100px as it should.  The new problem is when I move to a different nav label, it should animate from 100px back to 0px, but instead it just flashes there.

What am I missing?  Can't for the life of me see it and I'm sure its something stupidly obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are also transitioning the background property. This is not obvious because it's declared in an ancestor, and is just inherited. When you hover, the background changes inmediatly, and you see the transition of the width. When you hover out, the background changes inmediatly and you don't see the width transition.

You should do:

```
transition-property: background, width;
transition-duration: 0.6s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
```

with all the vendor prefixes, of course.

Your code is difficult to debug because you repeat lots of properties that aren't needed. Don't declare properties in a hover state when those are identicals to the base state, it is useless and makes more difficult to spot what is really the change. (Just an advice, hope you don't mind :-)

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/5kwsV/11/)

Comment: Oh yes, certainly there are multiple declarations that can be removed and I plan to do so.  I was having some odd inheritance issues here and there, so to be sure I wasnt experiencing any inheritance bugs I made sure everything was set no matter what.  I'll de-clutter it later.

Your explanation makes perfect sense.  I was completely forgetting that I was transitioning the visibility attribute, which would apply to background.  Thanks much!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I had also changed the visibility hidden in nav ul li > ul , that was the other property that was being transitioned; but i saw that it could be visible without problem